# How to check only one checker by CLANG?

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

How to check only one checker by CLANG?

When i use clang to check warning, i use this way

`# clang --analyze *.c`

I want to use ONLY ONE CHECKER to check it.

ex) core.DivideZero(C, C++, ObjC) only

Pls tell me some options to do it!

Answer (score 3):

To run a single checker using `clang --analyze`, add `--analyzer-no-default-checks -Xanalyzer -analyzer-checker=<checker>` to the command line.  For example:

```
$ clang --analyze --analyzer-no-default-checks -Xanalyzer -analyzer-checker=core.DivideZero hello.c
hello.c:44:12: warning: Division by zero
  return 6 / z;
         ~~^~~
1 warning generated.
```

In this case, `hello.c` contains three defects of various kinds that would be reported by default, but by enabling only `core.DivideZero`, just that one is reported.  The code fragment that provokes this report is:

```
int divide_by_zero()
{
  int z = 0;
  return 6 / z;
}
```

I figured out how to run a single checker mainly by looking at the [Clang Command Line Argument Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html), but that's not very clear so it needed some trial and error as well.  The `clang` program is sort of a multi-purpose front-end that calls other tools under the hood, so getting all the switches in the right places with the right `-X`, `-`, and `--` prefixes is a bit of a challenge.

Also useful is the list of [Available Checkers](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html), which includes names like `core.DivideZero`.

I tested with clang+llvm versions 3.7.1 and 8.0.1 on Linux/x86_64.